# Adding array to list overwrites previous elements

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a simple color gradient bitmap by iterating through all possible color combinations and adding each value to a `list`. Each individual `RGB` value is stored as an `int` array in the main `list`.

Problems occur for me when I am trying to `add` the array to my `list`. It overwrites all previous entries in the `list`, at last I end up with a list full of color arrays, all filled with the values 255. I know there must exist a better way to create a color spectrum bitmap than this rather clunky way, but I am very interested in why it behaves like this.

```
int[] temp = new int[3];
for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            temp[0] = r;
            temp[1] = g;
            temp[2] = b;
            colors.Add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that temp is an array and arrays are reference type. When you make change in it, it gets reflected in previously added values in colors.

You need to do

```
for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            int[] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = r;
            temp[1] = g;
            temp[2] = b;
            colors.Add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

This way every `temp` will be a fresh instance and all values of `colors` will be different.

Comment: It works, but I'm also interested in why it doesn't when I create the array before and just replace the values inside it. Does it have to do with the way lists work?

Comment: 10 minute waiting period.

Answer (score 2):

User [NikhilAgrawal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011959/nikhil-agrawal)'s answer is correct, I'd recommend you to use the dedicated `Color` struct in `System.Drawing` namespace. As the result you get [many useful methods and operators for free](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The your code becomes:

```
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(r,g,b));
        }
    }
}
```