# Last entry in dictionary overwrites first written entry when adding dictionary to json file

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, json.net

I have an existing json file which looks like this:

```
{ 
 "players": [],
 "games": []
}
```

I want to add objects to the `players` array so it looks like this:

```
{ 
 "players": [
  {
   "name": "Peter",
   "checksum": "6fa95b1427af77b3d769ae9cb853382f"
  },
  {
   "name": "John",
   "checksum": "61409aa1fd47d4a5332de23cbf59a36f"
  },
  {
   "name": "Bob",
   "checksum": "2fc1c0beb992cd7096975cfebf9d5c3b"
  }
 ],
 "games": []
}
```

Players are stored in a global `Dictionary<string, string>`. But in my implementation, the next element in the dictionary overwrites the first written element so when the loop is at `John` the next element would be `Bob` and then `Peter` gets replaced by `Bob`. The result of this looks like this:

```
{
  "players": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "checksum": "2fc1c0beb992cd7096975cfebf9d5c3b"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "checksum": "61409aa1fd47d4a5332de23cbf59a36f"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "checksum": "2fc1c0beb992cd7096975cfebf9d5c3b"
    }
  ],
  "games": []
}
```

This is my code:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("file.json");
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray jsonPlayerArray = (JArray) jsonObject["players"];

JObject newPlayerEntry = new JObject();
var sortedDict = PlayerChecksumDict.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
foreach (var item in sortedDict)
{
    newPlayerEntry["name"] = item.Key;
    newPlayerEntry["checksum"] = item.Value;
    jsonPlayerArray.Add(newPlayerEntry);
}
string modifiedJson = jsonObject.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("file-modified.json", modifiedJson);
```

Comment: You're only ever creating a single `JObject` which is used for all entries. Instead, move `JObject newPlayerEntry = new JObject();` into your loop, instead of having it outside.)

Comment: (This is definitely a duplicate of many questions - I'll try to find one, but in the meantime that should help you.)

Comment: This is the closest I've found - it's effectively the same, but only when you know the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179096 I haven't voted to close this question as a duplicate of that, but others may wish to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Similar questions to this have been asked several times, but I haven't been able to find a duplicate, so I figure it's worth answering instead.)

You're creating a *single* `JObject` instance, then modifying it multiple times within your loop. Each iteration will overwrite the data set in the previous iteration. Your `JArray` ends up with lots of references to the same `JObject`.

Instead, you need to create a new `JObject` for each entry in your dictionary. To do this, you just need to move the declaration of `newPlayerEntry` into the loop:

```
var sortedDict = PlayerChecksumDict.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
foreach (var item in sortedDict)
{
    JObject newPlayerEntry = new JObject();
    newPlayerEntry["name"] = item.Key;
    newPlayerEntry["checksum"] = item.Value;
    jsonPlayerArray.Add(newPlayerEntry);
}
```

Now each element in the `JArray` will be a reference to a different `JObject`.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that the `JArray` has multiple references to the same `JObject`. even though it's pretty obvious.